# Get pandas dataframe headers and create new Access table with them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have the following issue. I am creating offline ACCESS tool and many times I have to create an Access CROSSTAB that has undefined number of columns requiring manipulation of data in fields beyond the Access possibilities (due to complexity of operations or its size). So I import the query as PANDAS dataframe, manipulate it and I want to pass it back. I have rows of names under AGR_NAME header and various licence types as columns. Therefore I have first field/column as TEXT and columns as INTEGERS. The column headings are e.g. {52, CN, 55, XX, 71, PR} but the fields are populated with percents or integers.
How to import the headers (undefined number) as in the sql query and pass it back to Access database table with transformed values? 
The issue is that the name and number of columns can vary. Only the first columns is TEXT and the other are INTEGERS (not headers).
Basically I need to create the new table from the headers of the dataframe that can vary in number and populate it with transformed data.

```
LIC_TYPE CE 55 52 XE
AGR_NAME 1  0  1  2
XY       1  1  0  4
XZ       12 3  1  45 
XX       44 5  7  8
ZZ       0  0  1  0
```

The code I have so far is:

```
 import pyodbc 
 import pandas 
 import os 
 import sys 
 import struct


 print("running as {0}-bit".format(struct.calcsize("P") * 8))

 sources = pyodbc.dataSources() dsns = list(sources.keys()) dsns.sort()
 sl = [] 
 for dsn in dsns:
     sl.append('%s [%s]' % (dsn, sources[dsn])) print('\n'.join(sl))

 print(pyodbc.drivers())

 try:
     currdir = os.path.abspath(__file__) 

 except NameError: 
 import sys 
 currdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 

 DBfile = os.path.join(currdir, 'UNION.accdb') 
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %DBfile) 
 sql = "Select * FROM pivooo" df = pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

 df = df.set_index('AGR_NAME') res = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

 pandas.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format

 print(res.reset_index())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One approach would be to get a list of the column names with `df.keys().tolist()` and then construct a CREATE TABLE statement that you could run using `cnxn.execute`.

Comment: Hi Gord. Since the table size/number of column is unpredictable, I created export procedure for Python in xlsx and automated import procedure in Access VBA to create a table with first column/field as text and 50 columns/fields as integers. This way I create xlsx file, but do not have to open it as that takes a long time in larger files.